# File IO class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, io

For fun, I've made a practical file IO class in C++ with the purpose of being light and quick, and extendable for custom parsers. Here is the code:

**parser.h**

```
//
//  parser.h
//
//  Created by Taylor Shuler on 4/8/15.
//
//

#ifndef _parser
#define _parser

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Parser {
public:
    // constructors

    /// default
    Parser();

    /// copy
    Parser(const Parser &p);

    /// custom
    Parser(string filename);

    // destructor
    ~Parser();

    // public members
    string getFilename();
    list<string> getContent();

    // operators
    Parser& operator=(const Parser &p);
    Parser& operator-=(const Parser &p);
    Parser& operator+=(const Parser &p);

    bool operator==(const Parser &p) const;
    bool operator!=(const Parser &p) const;

    bool operator<(const Parser &p) const;
    bool operator>(const Parser &p) const;
    bool operator<=(const Parser &p) const;
    bool operator>=(const Parser &p) const;

    friend Parser operator+(const Parser &p1, const Parser &p2);
    friend Parser operator-(const Parser &p1, const Parser &p2);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &outstream, const Parser &p);
    //friend istream& operator>>(istream &instream, const Parser &p);
protected:
    // shared members
    void allocFilename(string filename, bool freeMemory = false);
private:
    // attributes
    char* filename;
    list<string> content;
};

#endif /* defined(_parser) */
```

**parser.cpp**

```
//
//  parser.cpp
//
//  Created by Taylor Shuler on 4/8/15.
//
//

#include "parser.h"

void panic(string msg) {
    cout << "ERROR: " << msg << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void Parser::allocFilename(string Filename, bool freeMemory) {
    if (freeMemory) {
        delete[] filename;
    }

    filename = new char[Filename.size()];
    strcpy(filename, Filename.c_str());
}

Parser::Parser() {
    allocFilename("");
}

Parser::Parser(string Filename) {
    allocFilename(Filename);

    ifstream file(Filename);

    if (file) {
        // we have one
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            content.push_back(line);
        }
    } else {
        // we don't have one
        panic("Could not find the file " + Filename + "!");
    }
}

Parser::Parser(const Parser &p) {
    // set the filename
    allocFilename(p.filename, true);

    // clear the destination for the text
    content.clear();

    // copy p's content over
    for (auto it = p.content.begin(); it != p.content.end(); it++) {
        content.push_back(*it);
    }
}

Parser::~Parser() {
    delete[] filename;
    content.clear();
}

string Parser::getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

list<string> Parser::getContent() {
    return content;
}

Parser& Parser::operator=(const Parser &p) {
    if (this == &p) {
        return *this;
    }

    // set the new filename
    allocFilename(p.filename);

    // make room for the new content
    content.clear();

    // add in p's content
    for (auto it = p.content.begin(); it != p.content.end(); it++) {
        content.push_back(*it);
    }

    return *this;
}

Parser& Parser::operator-=(const Parser &p) {
    for (auto it = p.content.begin(); it != p.content.end(); it++) {
        content.remove(*it);
    }

    return *this;
}

Parser& Parser::operator+=(const Parser &p) {
    for (auto it = p.content.begin(); it != p.content.end(); it++) {
        content.push_back(*it);
    }

    return *this;
}

bool Parser::operator==(const Parser &p) const {
    return content == p.content;
}

bool Parser::operator!=(const Parser &p) const {
    return content != p.content;
}

bool Parser::operator<(const Parser &p) const {
    return content < p.content;
}

bool Parser::operator>(const Parser &p) const {
    return content > p.content;
}

bool Parser::operator<=(const Parser &p) const {
    return content <= p.content;
}

bool Parser::operator>=(const Parser &p) const {
    return content >= p.content;
}

Parser operator+(const Parser &p1, const Parser &p2) {
    Parser sum(p1);

    for (auto it = p2.content.begin(); it != p2.content.end(); it++) {
        sum.content.push_back(*it);
    }

    return sum;
}

Parser operator-(const Parser &p1, const Parser &p2) {
    Parser diff(p1);

    for (auto it = p2.content.begin(); it != p2.content.end(); it++) {
        diff.content.remove(*it);
    }

    return diff;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &outstream, const Parser &p) {
    for (auto it = p.content.begin(); it != p.content.end(); it++) {
        outstream << *it << endl;
    }

    return outstream;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  parser
//
//  Created by Taylor Shuler on 4/8/15.
//
//

#include "parser.h"

int main() {
    Parser p1("test.txt"), p2("test2.txt"), p3, hr("hr.txt");
    p3 = p1 + p2;
    p3 -= hr;
    cout << p3;
}
```

Are there any ways that it could be improved? I am using C++11, so I've leveraged the usage of the `auto` keyword to remove excessive `list<string>::iterator` expressions.

Comment: What is the language that you are parsing?

Comment: It's not a specific language source file I'm parsing, if that's what you're asking. It just takes in any file and reads in its text. You can check out the full project and built executable on the GitHub project: https://github.com/T145/parser/tree/master/parser

Comment: So it's really a file reader, not a parser?

Comment: A "parser" usually involves a "lexer", which defines "tokens" ...the act of "parsing" implies somewhat *making programmatic sense out of some input*.

Comment: It basically is useful for text management. This is the core, and from it other custom parsers can be created to actually do things with the content that the class stores. This isn't literally a parser, but easily can be. I can implement a literal parsing functionality just fine on my own; I just wanted to be sure I was on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Let's start with the obvious:

1. `using namespace std` in the header file, very bad. If you've been looking around our site for a few months you should see this suggestion come up quite often, if not, then [read up on the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and learn about it.
2. Again something that comes up a lot, a global identifier starting with underscore. In this case it is aggravated for being a macro and with a common name used by libraries:

   > ```
   > #ifndef _parser
   > #define _parser
   > ```

   [Read up about the reserved C++ identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654). As a side recommendation, use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for `#defines` to differentiate them from actual C++ entities (the preprocessor is a mini-language inside C++).
3. Lots of unnecessary includes here:

   > ```
   > #include <stdio.h>
   > #include <stdlib.h>
   > #include <string.h>
   > ```

   This is not a C program, but when you do need a C header, you should reference it using its C++ alias, that is, starting with a `c` and with no `.h`, e.g.: `<cstdlib>`. But you don't need any of those anyway if you are writing clean C++. You do seem to need [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) (the C++ `std::string` header, not the same as [`<string.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring)), which is missing.
4. This was already mentioned in a OP comment: `Parser` is a bad name for a class that simply splits a source file into lines. [*Parsing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) is the process of *"analysing a string of symbols, either in natural language or in computer languages, conforming to the rules of a formal grammar"*. In simpler terms, parsing means making sense of a set of symbols and/or text. Your class is pretty far from that. Perhaps something like `TextFileReader` would be a more honest name.

#### The less obvious things and some nitpicking:

1. From a first glance, it looks strange that your class has so many operators for arithmetic and comparison. Since each "Parser" is just a container to the lines of a file, does it make sense to be able to add/subtract instances? Doesn't make much to me. Same for the comparisons. I can relate to comparing files for equality, but for `<= | >=` ordering has never occurred to me. Not by contents, at least.
2. Why do you use a `char*` for the `filename` is beyond my understanding, specially when the method that clones it already takes its input as a `std::string`. Storing it as a C++ string would be just so much simpler.
3. `exit`ing a C++ program is about as crude as it gets when it comes to error handling. Please just [**throw an exception**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept):

   ```
   void panic(const std::string & msg) {
       throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + msg + "\n");
   }
   ```

   The ideal would also be defining a custom exception type derived from `std::runtime_error`, if you want to refine it further.
4. You can use [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with C++11 to further simplify code like this:

   > ```
   > for (auto it = p.content.begin(); it != p.content.end(); it++)
   > ```

   Range-based:

   ```
   for (const auto & line : p.content) { /* `line` is a string */ }
   ```
5. Why do you have a `protected` section in your class? No signs of inheritance around, so all the internal details should be `private`.
6. `getFilename()` and `getContent()` should also be `const` since they don't (and shouldn't) mutate member data.
7. A `std::list` is probably going to have inferior performance if compared to a `std::vector` in this case due to poor data locality. With a list, each line is going to be allocated as a separate memory block (think about list nodes). Of course that without measuring it is impossible to say if this is a performance problem to your application, but at any rate, I would always start with a `vector` and only upgrade to other structures if there is a compelling reason.

Comment: The only issue I have with using the `vector` over a `list` is because the `vector` doesn't offer the same utility functions to manage the objects. My biggest complaint is that for `vector`, you have to utilize an erase-remove idiom, while with a list you can just call `remove`. Is there something that's not as "clunky" as a list but just as good as a vector in your opinion?

Comment: @T145, in that case, I don't think there is anything else. You might take a look at [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), which is something in between a list and a vector, though the interface is closer to a vector.

Comment: Check out the edit and let me know what you think!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> #ifndef _parser
> #define _parser
> ```

Identifiers that begin with a single underscore are semi-reserved. It would be better to pick something different. How about `INCLUDE_PARSER_H`?

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
> ```

You should be including the C++ versions of these headers, namely`<cstdio>`, `<cstdlib>`, and `<cstring>`.

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Please don't do this in a header file, as it pollutes the global namespace. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice There's not much impact to qualifying each `std::string` and the sole `std::list`.

> ```
>  friend Parser operator+(const Parser &p1, const Parser &p2);
>  friend Parser operator-(const Parser &p1, const Parser &p2);
> ```

Why are these declared as `friend`? The LHS is a `Parser`, they can be just regular operator methods:

```
Parser operator+(const Parser &rhs);
Parser operator-(const Parser &rhs);
```

> ```
> void panic(string msg) {
>     cout << "ERROR: " << msg << endl;
>     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
> }
> ```

the `class Parser` is not the application itself; it's included in another project. It's a violation of object-oriented design for a class to be able to kill the whole process. `Parser` doesn't own the process; `Parser` is used by the process and shouldn't be able to kill the process. How about `throw`ing an exception instead?

> filename = new char[Filename.size()];
>      strcpy(filename, Filename.c_str());

This is a buffer overrun. `Filename.size()` does not include space for a terminating `'\0'`. `strcpy()` expects there to be space to put in a terminating `'\0'`.

Also, why are you using this hybrid `string`/`char *` approach? What's wrong with a `string` member for the filename?

> ```
> Parser::Parser(const Parser &p) {
>     // set the filename
>     allocFilename(p.filename, true);
>
>     // clear the destination for the text
>     content.clear();
> ```

1. passing `true` to allocFilename causes it to call `free(filename)` which is uninitialized at this point.
2. `content.clear()` is pointless. You're constructing a new object instance.  The `std::list` starts out empty.

> ```
> Parser::~Parser() {
>     delete[] filename;
>     content.clear();
> }
> ```

What do you hope to accomplish by calling `content.clear()`? The automatic destructor will do that anyway.

I get the feeling you're doing a lot of things because you've seen other code using it, without understanding why. This is a dangerous way to learn how to program, as you don't really have ownership of your code.

Comment: So do I even need to `delete` anything? Would any leaks occur if I just removed the `allocFilename` function in favor of simple `filename = std::string`?

Comment: You need to balance every `new` with a call to `delete` (and every `new[..]` with a call to `delete[]`. Anything else, as long as the object goes out of scope the destructor will take care of it. That's the contract of using objects that C++ gives you.

Comment: @T145 I have no idea what you mean by `filename = std::string`. That doesn't make sense. The LHS is a variable and the RHS is a type (a class). You just need to have the `std::string` as a member variable, declared similarly to `std::string filename;`.

Comment: Ik; I just had that representing an object type, such as `filename = Filename` from my source, where `Filename` is of the `std::string` type. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Check out the edit and let me know what you think!

Comment: Please don't edit the code in your question. The code you post initially has to stay there as per codereview.SE policy. If you change your code and want others to know, your choices are (A) post it as an answer, if you believe it can't be improved more and/or don't want anyone else to suggest further changes, or (B) post it as a new question. Jamal reverted it.